# ORDER BY NULLS FIRST

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-order-by

I want to select some columns in 3 tables. I have a problem with this **ORDER BY NULLS FIRST**. Its been 2 Hours and it is still loading. I think my script is wrong or something I need to add. This is my script and it is running..

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN a.column1 IS NULL
             THEN 'ACTIVE'
             ELSE 'INACTIVE'
             END) as STATUS_DEF, <<some columns>>,

       (CASE WHEN b.column1 IS NULL
             THEN 'Active'
             ELSE) as STATUS_fnd_user, <<some columns>>,

                       c.column1||','||c.column2||','||c.column3

FROM table1 a, table2 b, table3 c
```

And then I want to Order them by **Active** First that's why I use **ORDER BY NULLS FIRST**. I tried this..

```
ORDER BY  a.column1, b.column1  NULLS FIRST;
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Since you are changing the NULL columns status as Active,why can't you try order by STATUS_DEF,STATUS_fnd_user in ur query and check...

Comment: You are not joining the three tables and therefor creating a cartesian product between the three. The number of result rows will be (  (rows in table1) * (rows in table2) * (rows in table3) ) - you can calculate that for yourself. That's why using **explicit** joins (`from table1 a join table2 b on ... join table3 c on ...`) is better - you can't forget to add the join condition.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I used **explicit** joins! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a_horse_with_no_name :)

Active...

```
FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.column1 IS NULL JOIN table3 c ON b.column1 IS NULL
```

Inactive...

```
FROM table1 a JOIN table2 b ON a.column1 = a.column1 JOIN table3 c ON b.column1 = b.column1
```